# Greater than operator given wrong response inside console.log in javascript

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have tried conditional operator inside `console.log()`. Less than `<` returns correct response but greater than `>` returns wrong response. Why?

```js
    console.log(5<6<7);
    //Output: true

    console.log(7>6>5);
    //output: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<` operator accepts two operands and yields a boolean result. Your code is effectively:

```js
let temp = 7 > 6;
console.log(temp);      // true
let result = temp > 5;
console.log(result);    // false
```

The reason `temp > 5` is `false` is that `true > 5` coerces `true` to a number (`1`), and `1 > 5` is false.

Insead, use `&&` if you want a logical AND condition:

```js
console.log(7 > 6 && 6 > 5); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

The lower than and greater than operators are evaluated from left to right (see [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)):

```
5 < 6 < 7 = (5 < 6) < 7 = true < 7 = 1 < 7 = true

7 > 6 > 5 = (7 > 6) > 5 = true > 5 = 1 > 5 = false
```

The boolean values (false/true) are converted to integers (0/1) here. ("If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to 1 if it is true and +0 if it is false." ([source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)))